# How to plot PCA with caret in R

Tags: r, statistics, pca, r-caret

I am getting PCA components using preProcess() from caret in R, and getting quantitative results.

```
dataPCA <- preProcess(data[1:ncol(data)-1], method = "pca", thresh = 0.95)
print(dataPCA)
print(dataPCA$rotation)
PCATrain <- predict(dataPCA,dataTrain[,1:ncol(dataTrain)-1])
PCATest <- predict(dataPCA,dataTest[,1:ncol(dataTest)-1])
```

However, I'd like to plot the components and variances explained, like you'd do with prcomp with plot(pca, type="1"). Is it possible using preProcess() or should I  run prcomp()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preProcess` doesn't save that info. I'd use `prcomp`.